# PyQGIS: Problems with imports in exec

Tags: python, plugins, qgis, pyqgis

I am working on a QGIS plugin that will allow me to run external Python scripts. I fetch the content of the scripts with `pathlib.Path(path_to_script).read_text()`, the execution is done with `exec()`. The same happens in QGIS when I open and execute a script via the Python editor.

If modules are imported in the Python script to be executed, they should be available in classes and functions. The following works outside of QGIS in pure Python:

This is the content of test.py:

```
import random

def test():
    print(random.randint(0,9))

test()
```

This is the way I execute it:

```
exec(pathlib.Path("path/to/test.py").read_text())
```

I get a random number between 0 and 9 in return. Now when I call the file from my QGIS plugin with the same code, the error message appears:

```
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

BUT if I run the script from the Python editor in QGIS, it does work.

If I import the module at the function level like

```
def test():
    import random
    print(random.randint(0,9))

test()
```

then I can run the script through my QGIS plugin as well.

Why does the first code block work in pure Python and via the Python editor in QGIS but not from a self written QGIS plugin, even if the code is just the same? Is there a namespace problem or something?